# Windows logoff user commandline

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I would to logoff a user using command line witch should be done using username not session id it should be done forcefully

i tried : `shutdown -l` but it works only for the current user also tried `logoff` command but it require a session name

EDITED :
i have tried a logoff script but it's not working.. any one can fix it ?

BATCH FILE

```
@echo off
query session > logoff.txt
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3" %%i in (logoff.txt) DO if [%%i]==[%1] logoff %%j
```

LOGOFF.TXT

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
 services                                    0  Disc                        
 console                                     1  Conn                        
>rdp-tcp#0         Administrator             2  Active                      
                   hi                        3  Disc                        
                   h                         4  Disc                        
                   Abdou                     5  Disc                        
                   Abdou76                   6  Disc                        
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
```

TRYING THE SCRIPT.. BUT FAILED

```
C:\dir>logoff.bat Abdou76

C:\dir>
```

User Abdou76 Still Loged in

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? How are the other users logged onto the system?

Comment: Windows Server 2012

Comment: Ahh it's not working because for disconnected users the first token (console, rdp-tcp#0, etc) doesn't exist...    this may be a little beyond batch scripting's capabilities.  Is a PowerShell script OK instead?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes i see, no prolem using a ps script or any else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have found the solution : using **batch code**

```
@echo off
query user > logoff.txt
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in (logoff.txt) DO if /I [%%i]==[%1] logoff.exe %%j
```

**Usage :**
logoff username

**NOTE :** The user name argument is intentionally NOT case sensitive (i.e.: username = UserName = USERNAME = USERname)

Answer (score 3):

### Batch:

There is no in-built Windows "logoff by name" utility that I'm aware of.

You could use a batch file to query the current sessions, pick out the names and session IDs, and then logoff matching users:

```
@echo off
query session > sessioninfo.txt
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3" %%i in (sessioninfo.txt) DO if [%%i]==[%1] logoff %%j
del sessioninfo.txt
```

Usage:

`batchfile.bat username`

The batch loads the results of `query session` into a text file.

It then uses a `for` loop, skipping the first two lines, to load the username and session ID tokens for each line into `I` and `J`.

`I` is checked to see if it matches the name provided as an argument (represented by `%1`), and if so `logoff` is used with the corresponding session ID.

---

After some comments and details regarding "disconnected" users, I'm thinking this would be better done in PowerShell.

### PowerShell:

Here's a PowerShell script that will logoff all sessions that match the user name you feed it, and this works if the user if active, or disconnected.

```
param (
    [string]$username = $(throw "-username is required.")
)

function Get-Sessions
{
    $queryResults = query session
    $starters = New-Object psobject -Property @{"SessionName" = 0; "UserName" = 0; "ID" = 0; "State" = 0; "Type" = 0; "Device" = 0;}
    foreach ($result in $queryResults)
    {
        try
        {
            if($result.trim().substring(0, $result.trim().indexof(" ")) -eq "SESSIONNAME") {
                $starters.UserName = $result.indexof("USERNAME");
                $starters.ID = $result.indexof("ID");
                $starters.State = $result.indexof("STATE");
                $starters.Type = $result.indexof("TYPE");
                $starters.Device = $result.indexof("DEVICE");
                continue;
            }

            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                "SessionName" = $result.trim().substring(0, $result.trim().indexof(" ")).trim(">");
                "Username" = $result.Substring($starters.Username, $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username) - $starters.Username);
                "ID" = $result.Substring($result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username), $starters.ID - $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.Username) + 2).trim();
                "State" = $result.Substring($starters.State, $result.IndexOf(" ", $starters.State)-$starters.State).trim();
                "Type" = $result.Substring($starters.Type, $starters.Device - $starters.Type).trim();
                "Device" = $result.Substring($starters.Device).trim()
            }
        } 
        catch 
        {
            $e = $_;
            throw "ERROR: " + $e.PSMessageDetails
        }
    }
}

$username = $username.ToLower()
$userSessions = Get-Sessions | ? { ($_.UserName).ToLower() -eq $username } | Select ID, UserName
$numberOfSessions = ($userSessions | measure).Count

if ($numberOfSessions -gt 0) {
    foreach ($session in $userSessions)
    {
       $sessionInfo = $session.Username + " (" + $session.ID + ")"
       Write-Host "Found $sessionInfo"
       logoff $session.ID /V
    }
} else {
    Write-Host """$username"" not found in session list."
}
```

Usage (from within PowerShell):
`.\LogEmOff.ps1 Abdou76`

The user name argument is intentionally NOT case sensitive (i.e.: AbDoU76 = Abdou76 = ABDOU76 = abdou76)

Comment: i tried logoff.bat Administrator but i got "if [65536] == [Administrator] logoff Listen"

Comment: the script is not working well, any advice ?

Comment: If you're seeing "if [65536] == [Administrator] logoff Listen" as the last line of output, then that means the "Administrator" user wasn't found in the list.  Keep in mind, it's case-sensitive. Please edit your question and include the output of `query session`, and include the command (batch + arguments) you ran.

Comment: i have edited the question, please check issue, thanks

Comment: thanks for your help, i have post another solution that meet my needs.