# Disconnect Windows users programmatically

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How can I easily disconnect all users (killing all apps running in background) whose name start with "KLTENE" ?

[image: img1 query session]

Currently, I proceed manually for each, which is tedious:
[image: img2 manual operation]

Comment: @Ramhound why? The `LOGOFF` is meant for that

Comment: Does this answer your question, or at least gives you something to work with? [Windows logoff user commandline](https://superuser.com/questions/1039138/windows-logoff-user-commandline)

Comment: @YisroelTech - A more accurate statement is we won’t write a script for the user.

Comment: That's indeed valid

Comment: Is this a server with all the active RDP session being concurrent, then I assume it is unless you are using the controversial RDPWrapper. In any event, there are terminal services policies you can set on servers with rules, etc. as well to handle this. Also in a domain, you can tell the AD account active time for an account and to force log out if logged in at that time. Not everything is necessarily a script but I have some doing this too all PS different than the posted answer on the dupe post, but see there for a feasible solution.